# Javascript function evaluation?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const debugMode = true;

// if "isCritical" is true, display the message regardless of
// the value of debugMode
function logger(message, isCritical) {
  if (isCritical) console.log(message);
  else if (debugMode) console.log(message);
}
```

In the above function, if I issued the following command, would the UTIL. inspect function evaluate "myObj" and not pass the data? I'd preferably not want UTIL.inspect to invoke if "isCritical" is set to false.

```js
logger(
  "myObj =\n" +
    UTIL.inspect(myObj, {
      showHidden: false,
      depth: null
    }),
  false
);
```

Is there a way to avoid the evaluation of the first parameter in the function when the second parameter is false?

Comment: The string is built *before* logger is invoked, the value of the second parameter is irrelevant.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this w/o evaluating "isCritical" before the function call?

Comment: Move the responsibility of inspecting inside the function, maybe? But otherwise no.

Comment: You would have to evaluate `isCritical` BEFORE you call `UTIL.inspect()` so `UTIL.inspect()` was inside a conditional.  You can do that outside of `logger()` before you call it or you can do that inside of `logger()`, but there's no way to do it like you are doing it because you're passing both `message` and `isCritical` so the code that creates the `message` argument runs in full.

Comment: Thank you jfriend00. This makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seperate your code for logging from the decision wether or not it should be executed.

And use a build pipeline that supports tree-shaking.

[Live example on rollupjs.org](https://rollupjs.org/repl/?version=2.21.0&shareable=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)

```
// config.js
export const DEBUG = false;
```

```
// logging.js
import { DEBUG } from "./config.js";

export const log = console.log; // or whatever
export const debug = DEBUG ? (...args) => logger("debug:", ...args) : () => void 0;
```

```
// main.js
import { DEBUG } from "./config.js";
import { log, debug } from "./logging.js";

log("this will always be logged");

if (DEBUG) {
    log("This will be eliminated when DEBUG=false")
}

// or more concise:
DEBUG && log(`This can be eliminated ${window.location = "/side-effect"}`);

debug("This approach works for simple things: " + location);
debug(`But it has limits ${window.location = "/side-effect"} :(`);
```